# How do I adjust tooltip in Pygal?

Tags: python, pygal

I tried to produce a bar chart that visualizes the most-starred projects on GitHub. I added `'label'` and `'xlink'` inside tooltips, however, `'label'` contents are not very well fit in for some items, also, some links are not shown up in certain projects' tooltip. See below,

[image]

Below is the Python code using Pygal module, run it and see the .svg file yourself.

```
import requests, pygal


url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=star'
r = requests.get(url)
repo_list = r.json()['items']

names, stars = [], []
for k in repo_list:
    names.append(k['name'])
    temp = {
            'value': k['stargazers_count'], 
            'label': k['description'],
            'xlink': k['html_url'],
           }
    stars.append(temp)

my_config = pygal.Config() 
my_config.x_label_rotation = 45

chart = pygal.Bar(my_config)
chart.title = 'GitHub, Python Most Starred Projects'
chart.x_labels = names
chart.add('', stars)
chart.render_to_file('MyFile.svg', force_uri_protocol = 'http')
```

How do I solve this problem, either by adjusting font size of tooltip or tooltip window size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a clean way to do this; I think you'd need to modify the .svg file directly. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/issues/324) on the Pygal project asking this question. Someone seems to have found [a solution](https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/issues/258) using `\n` and the `force_uri_protocol='http'`, but that doesn't work for me. On my machine `\n` just gets converted to a single space.

The best I could come up with is truncating the description to a certain number of characters, something like this:

```
temp = {
        'value': k['stargazers_count'], 
        'label': k['description'][:80] + "..." ,
        'xlink': k['html_url'],
       }
```

If you like this solution you can add some logic so short labels don't have the ellipsis at the end. I think this is the solution I'll use next time I run into this issue.

Comment: OMG! This is crazy, but are you Mr. Matthes??!!

Comment: Yes, I sometimes watch SO for Pygal questions. :)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! (btw, really enjoy the projects in your book...)